# Is there any way to skip Cypress failed test cases on github using CI/CD?

Tags: github, automation, cypress, github-actions

My yml script

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Install NPM dependencies, cache them correctly
      # and run all Cypress tests
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4.1.0
        with:
          build: npm run build
          start: npm start       
      - name: Jest Tests
        run: npm test
```

[image: screenshot of failed cases on git]